# sed is printing a substituted line twice

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I am running the following command:

```
find /home/debajdas/checkout -name 'pom.xml' -or -name '*.properties' | xargs sed -i 's/10.0.0.0.3/10.0.0.0.4/gpw changes'
```

But it's replacing

```
<version>10.0.0.0.3</version>
```

with

```
<version>10.0.0.0.4</version>
<version>10.0.0.0.4</version>
```

Why is it getting replaced with 2 lines ?

Comment: Why do you need  'w'?

Comment: Have you tried `man sed` or `info sed`?

Comment: Without w its giving me `sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to s'`

Comment: 'w' is needed to write changes to file 'changes'. Don't touch it if you need that file. Else you will get error as you show. If you don't need to write to changes file, remove 'w' and leading filename: 'sed s/.../g'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must remove 'p' that prints current pattern space.

```
sed -i 's/10\.0\.0\.0\.3/10.0.0.0.4/gw changes'
```

Comment: Giving me `sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: Checked it, works perfectly. you have removed 'w'? then remove next space and filename too.

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -i 's/\.3/.4/w changes'
```